# Tidying up remote-jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

am trying to run distribution test using one host & one slave machine.. while trying to run non-gui mode getting below error

Tidying up remote @ Wed Nov 09 10:00:00 IST YYYY (1320849384380) 
... end of run

trying with different scenarios to get work around but could not help, please help me if any one can got this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

"Tidying up remote" message is not an error, it's for debug purposes and it's printing it always to `System.out`.

It can't be disabled (without an enhancement) and you can ignore it if you don't need it

Comment: This is not the reason, it just logging end of run, you should search for errors in logs and/or check if you are missing properties or configuration

Comment: below I can found in jmeterlog

2018/02/22 11:41:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started 
2018/02/22 11:41:16 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Started remote host:  Slavehost (1519299676112) 
2018/02/22 11:42:01 INFO  - jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%) 
2018/02/22 11:42:01 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Finished remote host: Slavehost  (1519299721591) 
2018/02/22 11:42:06 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Interrupting RMI Reaper
please suggest possible workaround